# bada - Tab bar control

Tags: forms, tabs, controls, bada

I am new to bada programming and I am facing some problems. I am currently creating an app that consists of 6 tab bar item, each of which have a different form and have different controls in each form. I have tried following the example on http://www.badadev.com/forms-management-in-bada-part-3-managing-forms/ , however, I have set up all the controls in the form, but it does not respond and does not AppLog when I clicked on the button. Can someone please help me on this???

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to solve your problem that way(without seeing your code). Take look on a XmlParserApp example. It is using FormMgr and maybe you can get some good ideas. Or it is important that you have base class tabsForm that all the forms inherit?

Comment: Well, I did everything according to the link as mentioned above. But when I create the UI(like editfield, labels etc) in the form itself instead of the .h and .cpp files, it requires me to create a new class. Thus, I do not have any idea on how to link the UI(editfield, label etc) to the already created .h and .cpp files. :/